Detect a dark grey dot in a gray image with OpenCV
Up to now I could not find a way to find the center point of the dark grey spot in this gray image. What is the best approach to find the center point with OpenCV(sharp)? I tried to use erode or filtering the image but nothing worked as expected.

Thanks

The Laplacian of Gaussian filter or a Top-Hat filter are the best approaches in general for detecting dots. You need to match the dot size with the filter.

When you say “(sharp)”, do you mean you use C#? Please tag your language! (Though you might still get example code in other languages.)

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-find-gray-point/19477

yes I ment C# language in my case. With a top-hat filter I get a black image where the dot can not be seen anymore. When using a gaussian filter, the image will only be "blured" or smoothed.
